# Resources per version

Tags: c#, resources

I know it is possible to store localized versions of resources to be retrieved by the application.

I would like to use a similar principle and to store different versions of data into a resource file/assembly, then use the version as the key to retrieve this data. Is this possible? Is this a common technique?

The data I will be storing is UI Control data identifications.

So for example I would have multiple resources available per version:

```
Version 1.0    btnID = "thisButton1"  
Version 2.0    btnID = "thisButton2"
```

The application would determine automatically which resource to pick up based on the version currently being used.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Did you try to implement it on a simple Winforms project to see what would happen?

Comment: No, since the mechanism of determining the correct resource from an assembly is not so clear to me.

Comment: How about starting with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`? You'll need to map each version to a resource file name.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't include the full context in my question. What i meant was, include different resources for the application under test. So for app v1 and v2, i would keep Resources v1 and v2, and my consuming code would simply get the resource in a transparent way, without specifying which resource to grab (this would be done automatically).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use a resource file per version, so that each version may have different set of values for the same resources? Or what you intend to do is to have different resources in test and production environment?

Comment: I would like to keep a set of resources, each per version. The resource names would be identical, but their value would (or may change) between versions. This is very similar in concept to localization, where the same resource's value changes between different locales.

Comment: In that case, it seems not to be possible to use values from more than one version at a time. In other words, your app will use only one resource file at a time, right?

Comment: Yes this is perfectly fine. The only thing i'd like to automatically discover is "which resource DLL to use, according to the version".

Comment: Would you consider to wrap the resource file reading by a class you write and access resources through that class, or you might happen to use the resource syntax, like the <%$ ..%> in ASP.NET ? If not, you might have no issues loading a resource file by name based on your app version as @sq33G suggests. I'm afraid, however, that you will loose the neat access to values via properties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5587/discussion-between-ivaylo-slavov-and-liortal)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class that will wrap the access to the resources and load the correct resource file internally. Assuming you have chosen to name your resource file `Resources.1.0.0.0.resources`, you can do the following:

```
  public class ResourceReader
  {
      private static ResourceManager _resourceManager = new ResourceManager(
           "Resources." + System.Reflection.Assembly
               .GetExecutingAssembly()
               .GetName()
               .Version.ToString(),
           Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

      // If you have resource property btnID, you can expose it like this:
      public static string BtnID
      {
          get
          {
              return _resourceManager.GetString("btnID");
          }
      }

      // you can add other properties for every value in the resource file.
  }
```

All you need to do is to know the exact version of your application and to ensure such resource file exists. This can be cumbersome if you have enabled automatic versioning in the assembly info (by using 1.0.* for instance). Of course, you may choose not to use the entire version, but only the major or major and minor version numbers.

Comment: Can i still use Visual Studio's method of auto generating the class file for the resources in this way ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because VS will generate separate class for each resource. But, if you support limited number of versions, you might switch between them in the getter methods. The problem here is that each file (for each version) will stand for itself, even if the resource keys are the same, res files for 2 versions could not be used interchangeably (since they do not share common interface).